# Obtaining RGB data from image and writing it to CSV file with the corresponding pixel

Tags: python, image, numpy, python-imaging-library

I am experiencing some bugs with this code that is supposed to write the info from an image into a csv file.

Currently I have this piece of code that writes all the pixels of the image [its X,Y coordinates to be exact] to a csv file.

```
import PIL
import numpy as np

img_grey = Image.open('walkingpath_005004.jpg').convert('L')
print(img_grey.size)
# (300, 241)
x = 3
y = 4
#pix = img_grey.load()
#print(pix[x,y])

# Taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60783743/11089932
xy_coords = np.flip(np.column_stack(np.where(np.array(img_grey) >= 0)), axis=1)

# Add pixel numbers in front
pixel_numbers = np.expand_dims(np.arange(1, xy_coords.shape[0] + 1), axis=1)

#get rgb data
pixels = list(img_grey.getdata()) 
width, height = img_grey.size  
pixels = np.asarray(img_grey)

value = np.hstack([pixel_numbers, xy_coords, pixels])
print(value)
# [[    1     0     0]
#  [    2     1     0]
#  [    3     2     0]
#  ...
#  [72298   297   240]
#  [72299   298   240]
#  [72300   299   240]]

# Properly save as CSV
np.savetxt("outputdata.csv", value, delimiter='\t', fmt='%4d')
```

I need the RGB data of each pixel in 3 extra columns. As such, the format should be
`PixelNumber   X   Y   R   G   B`

Currently faced with this bug:
`ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 0, the array at index 0 has size 258063 and the array at index 2 has size 509`

I was looking at this link [How to read the RGB value of a given pixel in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138250/how-to-read-the-rgb-value-of-a-given-pixel-in-python)
but not sure how I can go about with incorporating it into my existing code.

Any and all help is appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [original solution for the `xy_coords`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60783743/11089932) must be adapted since you're now dealing with three-channel images instead of single-channel images. And, to get the RGB tuples for each pixel, you just need to reshape the NumPy array, you already have.

```py
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

img = Image.open('path/to/your/image.png')
print('Inspect a few pixels in the original image:')
for y in np.arange(3):
    for x in np.arange(3):
        print(x, y, img.getpixel((x, y)))

# Modified for RGB images from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60783743/11089932
img_np = np.array(img)
xy_coords = np.flip(np.column_stack(np.where(np.all(img_np >= 0, axis=2))), axis=1)
rgb = np.reshape(img_np, (np.prod(img_np.shape[:2]), 3))

# Add pixel numbers in front
pixel_numbers = np.expand_dims(np.arange(1, xy_coords.shape[0] + 1), axis=1)
value = np.hstack([pixel_numbers, xy_coords, rgb])
print('\nCompare pixels in result:')
for y in np.arange(3):
    for x in np.arange(3):
        print(value[(value[:, 1] == x) & (value[:, 2] == y)])

# Properly save as CSV
np.savetxt("outputdata.csv", value, delimiter='\t', fmt='%4d')
```

The two outputs for comparison:

```
Inspect a few pixels in the original image:
0 0 (63, 124, 239)
1 0 (65, 123, 239)
2 0 (64, 124, 240)
0 1 (74, 128, 238)
1 1 (66, 122, 239)
2 1 (68, 125, 239)
0 2 (173, 200, 244)
1 2 (86, 134, 239)
2 2 (80, 132, 240)

Compare pixels in result:
[[  1   0   0  63 124 239]]
[[  2   1   0  65 123 239]]
[[  3   2   0  64 124 240]]
[[301   0   1  74 128 238]]
[[302   1   1  66 122 239]]
[[303   2   1  68 125 239]]
[[601   0   2 173 200 244]]
[[602   1   2  86 134 239]]
[[603   2   2  80 132 240]]
```

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
PyCharm:       2021.1.1
NumPy:         1.19.5
Pillow:        8.2.0
----------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could try with glob.glob, what should help from an exactly code perspective

```
import numpy as np
import glob
import cv2
import csv

image_list = []

for filename in glob.glob(r'C:\your path to\file*.png'):    # '*' will count files each by one
    
    #Read
    img = cv2.imread(filename)
    flattened = img.flatten() 
    print(flattened) # recommend to avoid duplicates, see files and so on.

    #Save
    with open('output2.csv', 'ab') as f: #ab is set 
            np.savetxt(f, flattened, delimiter=",")
```

Cheers

Also, find an easier method that is making **fast and not weight** image/csv

```
image_list = []
with open('train_train_.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter ='-')

    for filename in glob.glob(r'C:\your path to\file*.png'):

        img = cv2.imread(filename)
        image_list.append(img)
        csv_writer.writerow(img)
        print(img)
```